# Prevent AngularJS service from reloading?

Tags: angularjs

My understanding is that AngularJS services are similar to singletons and thus are only instantiated once. As such, they should be useful for storing things like "isUserLoggedIn." But, with my application it appears that the service runs on every page load. This causes problems because it resets values.

What am I doing wrong?

I have an index.html like this:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
<div class="container" ng-view=""></div>
</body>
```

My service looks like this:

```
MyApp.service('sharedProperties', function () {

    var isLoggedIn = false;

    return {
        getProperty: function () {
            return isLoggedIn;
        },
        setProperty: function(value) {
            isLoggedIn = value;

        }
    }
})
```

The problem is whenever I go from one route/page to the next this service keeps getting called and setting isLoggedIn to false.

I have tried 'forcing' caching to improve the chances of the index.html won't reload and thus cause the service to fire off but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Something's wrong with your navigation: it shouldn't reload the page, but simply change the route. That said, you should support page reloads, and thus store the logedIn status in a persistent location: a cookie, local storage, ...

Comment: Unless you explicitly use some storage mechanism (client side or server side) any page reload will reinit the services (essentially all JS code)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
MyApp.service('sharedProperties', function () {


    service = {
        isLoggedIn : false,

        getProperty: function () {
            return service.isLoggedIn;
        },

        setProperty: function(value) {
            service.isLoggedIn = value;

        }
    };
    return service;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CacheFactory instead, which could help out more..

Answer (score 0):

If you make your service a value or a constant this should go away.

```
myModule.value('sharedProperties', {
    isLoggedIn : false,

    getProperty: function () {
        return service.isLoggedIn;
    },

    setProperty: function(value) {
        service.isLoggedIn = value;

    }
});
```

The angular docs are a decent read about the [difference between constants, values, services, factories, providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/object/%24provide#value).